# Create Bold version from an existing monospaced Font while keeping the width

Tags: fonts, bold, monospace

I have a website in which I use a monospace font. But there are major differences in different browsers concerning the width of a character. **It is essential that the font width stays exactly the same.**

I have tried: `font-weight: bold;` but this is browser dependent and I cannot make up for the extra width using a negative `letter-space` value.

I have tried to create my own new derived font in Type Light 3.2, but this is very hard especially with curved characters it is hard to change.

I have tried to double the text with an absolute div behind it and set a margin of 2px change, which worked out very well, but the downside of this is that you need a lot of div's which makes IE7 and IE8 terribly slow when using large texts.

Is there another way to (preferred automatically) derive a bold font from a ttf/eot/woff/svg font? I know Java for example can create bold fonts, but will I be able to save it to a new font file? Any way will do for me.

Comment: Is there no other way apart from emboldening the text that will work? Perhaps a different background colour or using, e.g. #101010 for normal text and #000000 for emphasis?

Comment: I thought of this as well. Even with #333333 versus #000000 the difference remains small compared to using `font-weight: bold`.

Another solution might be to put the text into a SPAN, together with a DIV which contains the same text as in the SPAN. But then set the DIV to absolute position, and set it on left position 1 or 2 pixels. This worked very nice and the results were exactly what was required. But there was a huge drawback in the performance concerning IE7 and IE8. The page was loading really slow and the browser GUI froze for countable seconds because of so many DIV/SPANs (lots text).

Answer (score 2):

You could use CSS3 a [`text-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow) trick:

```css
text-shadow: -.5px 0,  0 .5px,  .5px 0,  0 -.5px;
```

Of course, that won't work on old IE, but there you can use a [glow filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532995%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```css
filter: glow(color:black,strength=1);
```

Also note that, on all browsers I tested, when using the built-in `font-family: monospace`, a bold weight didn't alter the width of a character. So it might not need a negative `letter-spacing`.

```css
font-weight: bold;
```

```css
div {
  font-family: monospace;
}
.ie-trick-bold {
  filter: glow(color:black,strength=1);
}
.css3-trick-bold {
  text-shadow: -.5px 0,  0 .5px,  .5px 0,  0 -.5px;
}
.normal-bold {
  font-weight: bold;   
}
```

```html
<div class="css3-trick-bold">Hello World! (CSS3 trick)</div>
<div class="ie-trick-bold">Hello World! (IE trick)</div>
<div class="normal-bold">Hello World! (default bold)</div>
<div>Hello World! (normal text)</div>
```

Comment: I like your idea of using text-shadow, it's a pity most user-agents do not support CSS3 yet.
Probably the Font-family 'Monospace' you are using already has a built-in Bold style. The difference is, I used my own Font. Thus the browser will have to generate the Bold version. And there are different approaches to generate a Bold version of a Font (which is quite interesting, look it up). But the different approaches result in a different font width. My solution was to create my own Bold version using a Font Creator program and change the font-family to the bold version.

Comment: Is it so important to have your own monospace font? All of them look like the same for me; if the problem is that your font doesn't have a built-in bold style, maybe you could find another font which does.

Comment: Sorry, it really is hard in my case. Somehow, I always get these cases which nobody else has...
The problem is the `a`, I needed a mono-spaced font in which the character `a` is in the same way you would write it, thus like a `d` without the vertical bar being so long if you understand.

Comment: @Yeti But does it work, using `border-shadow` + `filter:glow`?